# 外卖 - Does this read as ( Take Away ) in regards to a meal?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

I am trying to find symbols for a restaurant that does Asian Takeaway food.
I want to know if this is the correct way to write "TAKEAWAY"

Comment: Do you mean carryout order? Never heard of "takeaway order". in the restaurant business. How does it work, pickup only?

Answer (score 2):

In daily usage, 外卖 can mean both "takeaway" and "a takeaway meal".
If you want to be more specific, you may use "外带", which can only mean "takeaway" but not "a takeaway meal".